# How do I run a graphical application in a virtual console besides <Alt+F7>?

Tags: xorg, gui, window-manager, window, virtual-console

I want to run `R` in a virtual console and `RCommander` in a separate virtual console. Or maybe I want to run a game in a virtual console and shut off the desktop. Or maybe I want to pipe an `ssh -x` terminal to a virtual console.

How can I tell Virtual Console 3 to open a graphical virtual console in Virtual Console 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "graphical virtual console" you want is an X server instance. You can start a new one as root with

```
$ X :1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a client startup script, for example call it `~/myxinitrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
metacity &
xterm
```

(I avoid to call it `~/.xinitrc` to not interfere with other operations).

Then, assuming you already have a server running on :0 and corresponding to vt7, this is how you can start a server on :1 and vt8. Go to vt1 and execute:

```
XINITRC=~/myxinitrc xinit -- :1 vt8
```

from the xterm you get, you can start other applications of your preference.